# How to compare two custom post types using ACF flex layouts

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using a second custom post type to set default theme values inside flex content layouts.  Below is my working code, however, it is a little verbose and I was wondering if this is the correct method of comparing the two.  If the post has a value for the field, it uses that - if not, it pulls the matching field value from the second CPT.

```
//theme vars
$theme_padding = $theme_background_color = $theme_padding = $theme_height = $theme_color = $theme_font_family = $theme_font_size = '';

$theme = get_field('theme_picker');

if( $theme ):

  foreach( $theme as $post):
    setup_postdata($post);
    while ( have_rows('nav') ) : the_row();

      if( get_row_layout() == 'right_aligned' ):

        $theme_background_color = get_sub_field('background_color');
        $theme_padding = get_sub_field('padding');
        $theme_height = get_sub_field('height');
        $theme_color = get_sub_field('color');
        $theme_font_family = get_sub_field('font_family');
        $theme_font_size = get_sub_field('font_size');

      endif;

    endwhile;

   endforeach;
   wp_reset_postdata();

 endif;

//var = if no post level theme var, use theme var
$background_color = get_sub_field('background_color') ?: $theme_background_color;
$padding = get_sub_field('padding') ?: $theme_padding;
$height = get_sub_field('height') ?: $theme_height;
$color = get_sub_field('color') ?: $theme_color;
$font_family = get_sub_field('font_family') ?: $theme_font_family;
$font_size = get_sub_field('font_size') ?: $theme_font_size;



// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('nav_type') ): ?>

<table bgcolor="<?php echo $background_color; ?>" class="emailwrapto100pc" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style=" width:100%; height: <?php echo $height; ?>;">
```